# A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree in flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, provider

I have a todo app which uses `provider` for state management and `sqlite` database.

In the app I am trying to add `Dismissible` widget to delete item.

But the problem is when I try to delete item It does get deleted from `database` but I get error on the screen.I am new to flutter.

[image: dismissible image]

> error in console.

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Dismissible-[<'howll'>](dirty, dependencies: [Directionality], state: _DismissibleState#98163(tickers: tracking 2 tickers)):
A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.

Make sure to implement the onDismissed handler and to immediately remove the Dismissible
widget from the application once that handler has fired.
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  TaskListTile file:///C:/Users/adity/Desktop/flutter-app/todoye/lib/widgets/task_list_view.dart:14:22
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _DismissibleState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/dismissible.dart:526:11)
#1      _DismissibleState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/dismissible.dart:533:8)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4047:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3941:15)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3738:5)
...
```

This is my code.

> task_list_tile.dart

```
Dismissible(
      key: Key(taskTitle),
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        deleteCallback();
        Scaffold.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("$taskTitle removed.")));
      },
      child: ListTile(
           title: Text(
          '$taskTitle',  
        ),
```

> task_data.dart

```
void deleteTask(int id) {
    taskDatabaseManager.deleteTask(id);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

> databse_connection.dart

```
Future<void> deleteTask(int id) async {
    await openDb();
    await _database.delete(
      'tasks',
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
  }
```

> task_list_view.dart

```
class TaskListView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TaskData>(
      builder: (context, taskData, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: taskData.taskCount,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return TaskListTile(
                taskTitle: taskData.tasks[index].name,
                isChecked: taskData.tasks[index].isDone,
                checkboxCallback: (checkboxState) {
                  taskData.updateTask(taskData.tasks[index]);
                },
                deleteCallback: () {
                  taskData.deleteTask(taskData.tasks[index].id);
                },
              );
            });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code from the ListView to the Dismissible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you dismiss a `Dismissible`, you should remove it from the widget tree. In your case, you are showing a `Dismissible` for each item of `taskData`, so if you dismiss the `Dismissible` of an item you should remove that item from the list.

So, in the `deleteCallback`, after doing `deleteTask()`, you should do `taskData.removeAt(index)` inside `setState()`.

Comment: I am bit confused where should I put them in `task_list_view.dart` file on `task_list_tile.dart` file actually I am using `Consumer` in `task_list_view.dart` file That's why.

Comment: in `task_list_view.dart` since in `task_list_tile.dart` you don't have a reference to the index or the list.

Comment: But there it says `removeAt` is not defined.

Answer (score 10):

If you are sure about the your dismissible widget is removed. Try to fix `key`.
Key should be unique. If tasks's id is unique,

```
key: Key(taskData.tasks[index].id)
```

If you didn’t have any other constant and unique data, you could try

```
key: UniqueKey()
```

Answer (score 1):

I used UniqueKey() instead of Key(taskData.tasks[index].id) and It's right.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).